# Show images with effect on respective menu hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I show an image with an effect when the cursor is hovering over a respective menus like [this](http://2009.legworkstudio.com/#/work) using jquery or css?

Can I do it just by css, or do I have to use jquery?

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title></title>    
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#menu img" ).on( "click", function() {
                $("#menu img" ).hide( 1500 );
            });
         });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
     <div id="menu">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="">Menu1<img src="images/1.jpg" /></a></li>                    
             <li><a href="">Menu2<img src="images/2.jpg"/></a></li> 
             <li><a href="">Menu3<img src="images/3.jpg"/></a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @brandonjordan Please read the question again

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use JavaScript/jQuery to show an image on mouse hover. You can use plain CSS:

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu li:hover {
    background-image: url('path/to/my/image.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px /* set x and y coordinates */
}
```

But if you want to add an effect to the appearing of the image, you will have to use jQuery as drafted in Tushars answer.

(Actually, in CSS3 you can use animations as well; [examples here](https://www.google.com/search?q=css3+animation). But be aware that this can cause cross browser and downward compatibility problems.)

Comment: Can you be more precise? (This sounds a little like "I love that website, please tell me how to copy that!") Do you want the same menu and when you hover over the `li`-entries it shows the pictures right at the top right edge of your `li`? Then this answer is exactly what you're looking for!

Comment: By the way: You then have to remove the `img` elements from within the `li` tags!

Comment: actually i am try to generate the effect of the website i mentioned

Comment: Which effect exactly? The one I described?

Comment: also in the above code when i hover on anchor or image the image is displayed where as the image should only be displayed when i hover on anchor and when the mouse is moved away from anchor image should fade out even if the mouse is on image. so i guess the img shouldn't be a part of anchor so i tried to put the anchor outside anchor but inside li. but then what changes should i make in jquery code

Comment: How can you hover an image if you have removed the `img` from the `li` tag?

Comment: Plus what I said: If you want any kind of animation you won't be able to avoid jQuery.

Comment: finally got what i was looking for :)

Comment: Please reward the answer that solved your question by marking it appropriately. (Or post your own answer if none of the existing solved it. To help others with the same problem.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Use CSS transition:**

```
#menu li img {
  -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
background-image: url('path/to/my/image.png');
}
#menu li img:hover {
background-image: url('path/to/my/image.png');
}
```

Change the `background-image` or the `background-position` on `:hover`

Comment: As I said, watch out for CSS3. It's not yet widely supported.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Most use chrome, safart or firefox, and the code I just showed you is widely supported, I didn't just put -webkit-. and not a lot of people use IE and all those browsers that don't support HTML5 and CSS3 and all the new web technologies.

Comment: I'm just lifting my finger to create awareness. I personally always develop as if there would be no Internet Explorer (actually: for me it doesn't exist!).

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Hide all images first, so that they don't appear until you hover */
$('#menu li img').hide();

$('#menu li').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('img').fadeIn('slow');
},function(){
   //do what you want when mouse out
});
```

[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: I know my example in no where near to to the effect i am looking but i am looking some thing like this  http://2009.legworkstudio.com/#/work

Comment: Did you put this into the `$(document).ready()` part? That is required!

Comment: @AbhishekKumar this relies on there being an `<img/>` tag *within* the respective `<li/>`.

Comment: yes now the images appear on hovering but it stays there. It will look better if on removing mouse it goes away

Comment: actually i am try to generate the effect of the website i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

// Load this script once the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    // Get all the thumbnail
    $('menu li a').mouseenter(function(e) {

        // Calculate the position of the image image
        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

        // Set the z-index of the current item, 
        // make sure it's greater than the rest of thumbnail items
        // Set the position and display the image image
        $(this).css('z-index','15')
        .children("div.image")
        .css({'top': y + 10,'left': x + 20,'display':'block'});

    }).mousemove(function(e) {

        // Calculate the position of the image image            
        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

        // This line causes the image will follow the mouse pointer
        $(this).children("div.image").css({'top': y + 10,'left': x + 20});

    }).mouseleave(function() {

        // Reset the z-index and hide the image image 
        $(this).css('z-index','1')
        .children("div.image")
        .animate({"opacity": "hide"}, "fast");
    });

});
```